# Getting an 'x' in the url derived from django regex

Tags: regex, django, python-3.x

I am trying to generate an URL using regex and have got it to an extent. But, the problem is there is an 'x' in the URL which I don't want there, without it the URL is perfect. I have tried few changes on the regex but removing or adding anything throws an error.

*views.py*

```
def clothes_details(request,slug):
    item = data.objects.get(slug=slug)
    print(item)
    return render(request,clothes_details.html,{'item':item})
```

*urls.py*

```
url(r'^(?P<designerlink>)[\w-]+/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',views.clothes_details,name='clothes_details'),
```

*item.html*

```
<div class='items'>
        {% for item in all_clothes %}
        <div class='item'>
            <a href="{% url 'clothes_details' designerlink=item.designerlink slug=item.slug %}">
                <img src="{{item.itemimage.url}}" style="width:350px;height:450px;">
            </a> 
            <p>{{item.itemcode}}</p>
            <p>{{item.itemprice}}</p>
            <p>{{item.itemname}}</p>
        </div>
```

The result is getting  'http://127.0.0.1:8000/designernamex/dressname/' but I need to get 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/designername/dressname/'

Comment: The capture part of the `url` does *not* encapsulate the `[\w+]`.

Comment: Furthermore it is strange that you have a `designerlink` parameter, but that is not part of the `clothes_details(..)` function.

Comment: I tried,                                                                                                            def clothes_details(request,designerlink):
    item = data.objects.get(designerlink=designerlink)
    print(item)
    return render(request,clothes_details.html,{'item':item})                           
 but still I get the same url with an 'x'. I used slug to filter as I kept slug unique for every item.

Comment: I also tried                                                                                                          def clothes_details(request,designerlink,slug):
 item1 = datawh.objects.get(designerlink=designerlink)
 item2 = datawh.objects.get(slug=slug)
 item = datawh.objects.filter(designerlink=item1).filter(slug=item2)
 print(item)
 return render(request,clothes_details.html,{'item':item})
                     
 but still I get the same url with an 'x'.